# How can make sure code after my ajax request only runs if the request was a success?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a link, delete, that removes an item from an array, and then removes a row from a table on my html page.

It runs the ajax request first to amend the array, then removes the row. If for some reason the ajax request was to fail then the html table row would still be deleted I think.

Is there a way to make sure subsequent code afer the ajax request only runs if it is successful? I tried moving it into the success function but then it didn't run at all..

This is how I have it set up at the moment...

```
$(document).ready(function () { //delete 
    $(document).on("click", "a[class='del']", function () {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id"); //<----- get the ID of the column      
        $.ajax({
            //contentType: "text",
            url: 'proDel.php', //the url you are sending datas to which will again send the result
            type: 'GET', //type of request, GET or POST
            dataType: 'json', // jQuery will parse the response as JSON
            data: 'val1=' + ID, //Data you are sending 
            success: function (data) {
                // do nothing, array was amended in php file                       
            }
        })

        //Code here that deletes the table row(runs whether the array was changed or not!!
    })
})
```

Comment: `"a[class='del']"`? simply `"a.del" is the same.

Comment: You had the right idea moving it into the success function that is where the code belongs, post the actual code and we can resolve.

Comment: And similarly `ID= this.id` is the same as `ID= $(this).attr("id");`

Comment: I have a feeling you're using `$(this)` in the success function, but `this` will have a different value in a different context.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour `a[class="del"]` and `a.del` are not the same. The first selector won't match `<a class="del other-class"></a>` and the second will.

Comment: @JasonP, you're right. I should have said *effectively*, or *for the apparent purpose* they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that you are not returning valid JSON.

You were correct in thinking that you should move the code that deletes the table row into the `success` callback. You say you tried that, but the `success` callback was not executed.

Since you specify `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery will attempt to parse the response body into a JavaScript object (or array or null). If the response body cannot be parsed (because it is not valid JSON), jQuery will call the `error` callback, rather than the `success` callback.

An empty response body is not valid JSON. You must at least return "null". Or if you do not plan on returning any data, just change to `dataType: 'text'`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code that deletes row to success callback.

```
$.ajax({
            //contentType: "text",
            url     : 'proDel.php', //the url you are sending datas to which will again send the result
            type    : 'GET', //type of request, GET or POST
            dataType: 'json', // jQuery will parse the response as JSON
            data    : 'val1='+ID, //Data you are sending 
            success : function (data){
                  // Code here that deletes the table row
           }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try you ajax with success parameter as well as an error to see if there is a problem, hope this helps..

```
$(document).ready(function (){   

  $(document).on("click", "a[class='del']", function(){ 
     var elem = $(this); //to make $(this) accessible in you success callback
     var ID= elem.attr("id"); // get  ID of the column      

     $.ajax({
           url     : 'proDel.php', //the url you are sending datas to
           type    : 'GET', //type of request, GET or POST
           dataType: 'json', // jQuery will parse the response as JSON
           data    : 'val1='+ID, //Data you are sending 
           success : function (data){
                // success, Code here that deletes the table row , do something with 'elem'          
            },
             error: function(x,e) {  
               //log error if any
              console.log("failed with: "+x.status+", e="+e+", response="+x.responseText);
            }
          });

        });    
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery 1.5 you may use [chainable methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) of object returning by `jQuery.ajax()`. In your case (ensure executing code on ajax request completion) you have to use [`deferred.always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) method. Somehow like this:

```
$.ajax({
...
})
.always({
//Code here that deletes the table row
})
```

In earlier jQuery versions you have to use `complete` option (handler) in `jQuery.ajax()` for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that when looking at the ajax request `success` does not mean that the request returned a correct/true value. That just means that there was a response from the other end.

That tripped me up during my first couple times working with and debugging ajax calls.
I don't know if that's part of what is not working for you here, but something to consider.

Secondly, and to answer your real question, you'll have to put a function call in the success branch, else it might never get called, or be called at a non-deterministic time (the whole nature of an asynchronous call).

```
var a = function(){
  $.ajax({
    success : function (){
      //  code here fires if there is a response to your ajax request
      //  you should put in an function callback here to check the response for 
      //  your success conditions.
      //  if your conditions are met, make the changes that you need to
      b();
    }
    failure: function() {
      //  code here fires if the ajax request receives no response
    }

  })
  //  any code here will fire immediately after the ajax call is fired.
  //  it will not wait for the ajax response.
}
var b = function(){
  //  stuff you want to do according to the ajax response parameters
}
```